# Why am I getting an Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 12 error?

Tags: string, phone-number, outofrangeexception

```
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
at TelephoneNumberTranslator.correctFormat(TelephoneNumberTranslator.java:97)
at TelephoneNumberTranslator.getPhoneNumber(TelephoneNumberTranslator.java:61)
at TelephoneNumberTranslator.main(TelephoneNumberTranslator.java:22)
```

Hello,

I have read about the off-by-one error, and that is a possibility.  I have fooled around with my code the best I can, though, and the results have not differed.  I removed the last while loop from the correctFormat method; however, I was prompted to enter my name and then the program stopped.  I even entered an extra message box at the end of the convertPhoneNumber method to see if the string just wasn't being returned for some reason, but I got no result from that either.  I know that this is a common problem, but from what I have read, I am still not wrapping my head around it.  This is only the fifth or sixth program I have written, though, so I'm not too flustered.  Just someone pointing me on the right path that won't mind if I write them back and forth a bit would be helpful.  Gracias,

Andy`

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;                             //Needed for user dialogue boxes
import java.io.*;                                          //Needed for File I/O classes
/*
    PROGRAM: TelephoneNumberTranslator.java
    Written by Andrew Sechrist
    On 10/13/15
    For CPS 121 - JAVA Programming
    This program requests user input for their name and a telephone number that may be a combination of alphanumeric characters.  
    It checks the string for correctness and converts lower case alphabetic characters to upper case.  It then outputs the data.
*/

public class TelephoneNumberTranslator                      //This line creates the class TelephoneNumberTranslator
{
//This line creates the Main Method for the above class
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException                     
   {                                                        //This line opens the body of the Main Method to begin creating the class
      String userName;                                      //For the user's name; initialized with a call to method getName
      String phoneNumber;                                   //To hold the value of the string phoneNumber  
      char eachSymbol;                                      //For a specific symbol from the phone number String

      userName = getName();                                 //Calling the getName method to obtain the user's name
      phoneNumber = getPhoneNumber();                       //Calling the getPhoneNumber method to obtain the user's phone number input

      /*Making sure the phone number is in the correct 
      format with a call to the correctFormat method*/
      String formattedPhoneNumber = correctFormat(phoneNumber);

      //Converting the phone number correctly with a call to the convertPhoneNumber method
      String convertedPhoneNumber = convertPhoneNumber(formattedPhoneNumber);

      //Call method displayResults to display the results
      displayResults(userName, formattedPhoneNumber, convertedPhoneNumber);               
   }
/**
      The getName method prompts the user to enter their name
      It then returns their name to the main method
      @return The name the user entered is returned
   */

   public static String getName()
   {                                                      
      String name =                                            //For the user's name locally in the getName method
         JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name: ");
      return name;                                             //Return the user's name            
   }

   /**
      The getPhoneNumber method prompts the user to enter a phone number
      It then checks the phone number for correctness with a call to the correctFormat method
      It finally returns the phone number to the main method
      @param getPhoneNumber
      @return The phone number the user entered is returned
   */

   public static String getPhoneNumber()
   {                                                      
      String thisNumber =                                      //Get a phone number
         JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You will be entering a telephone number.\n Make sure that it is in the format XXX-XXX-XXXX\n Any X can be any" + 
         " numer 0 to 9 inclusive\n or any alphabetical English letter A through Z inclusive.\n Please enter the telephone number: \n");
      String phoneNumber = correctFormat(thisNumber);
      return phoneNumber;                                      //Return the phone number            
   }
/**
      The correctFormat method receives an argument of telephoneNumber from the getPhoneNumber method
      It detects any format errors and prompts the user to correct them by inputting the phone number again
      It finally returns the phone number input with any formatting errors corrected to the getPhoneNumber method
      @param telephoneNumber
      @return the user's inputted telephone number in the correct format
   */

   public static String correctFormat(String telephoneNumber)
   { 
      int firstHyphen = telephoneNumber.indexOf('-');          //Holds position of first hyphen
      int secondHyphen = telephoneNumber.lastIndexOf('-');     //Holds position of second hyphen
      int stringSize = telephoneNumber.length();               //Holds the length of the telephone number string
      char symbol;                                             //To hold the referenced value in the present position of the telephoneNumber string
      while (firstHyphen != 3 || secondHyphen != 7)            //A while loop to make sure that hyphens are placed correctly
      {
         telephoneNumber = 
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("The number you enter must be in the format XXX-XXX-XXXX\n It seems that you have misplaced or forgotten " + 
            "the hypens (-).\n They are necessary, so please re-enter a telephone number with them placed correctly: \n");
      }
      while (stringSize > 12)                                 //A while loop to correct situations where there are not 12 characters in the string
      {
         telephoneNumber =
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("The number you enter must be in the format XXX-XXX-XXXX\n Any X can be any numer 0 to 9 inclusive\n" +
            "or any alphabetical English letter A through Z inclusive.\n Please re-enter a telephone number: \n"); 
      }
      int i = 0;                                               //An accumulator variable
      char ch = telephoneNumber.charAt(i);                     //Holds the first char value in the phone number string

      //A while loop to determine that values are either hyphens or letters or digits
      while (ch != ' ') 
      {
         ch = telephoneNumber.charAt(i);                       //Holds the char value in the next position of the telephoneNumber string
         if (ch != '-')
         {
            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch))                //Prints an error message if the char is not an English letter or digit
            {
               telephoneNumber =
                  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("The number you enter must be in the format XXX-XXX-XXXX\n Any X can be any numer 0 to 9 inclusive\n" +
                  "or any alphabetical English letter A through Z inclusive.\n Please re-enter a telephone number: \n"); 
            }
         }
         i++;
      }
      System.exit(0);                                          //Terminate JOptionPane's running thread 
      return telephoneNumber;                                  //Return a correctly formatted phone number                        
   }
/**
      The correctFormat method receives an argument of telephoneNumber from the getPhoneNumber method
      It detects any format errors and prompts the user to correct them by inputting the phone number again
      It finally returns the phone number input with any formatting errors corrected to the getPhoneNumber method
      @param telephoneNumber
      @return the user's inputted telephone number in the correct format
   */

   public static String convertPhoneNumber(String telephoneNumber)
   {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();                  /**Initializing a StringBuilder class object to hold all generated values 
                                                                in one accessable String*/
      int i = 0;                                               //An accumulator variable
      char ch = telephoneNumber.charAt(i);                     //Holds the first char value in the phone number string
      while (ch != ' ')                                        //A while loop to determine whether there is another character to check            
      {
         char symbol = telephoneNumber.charAt(i);              //To hold the referenced value in the present position of the telephoneNumber string 
         if (Character.isLetter(symbol))                       //To convert lower case alphabetic values to upper case
         {
            char value = Character.toUpperCase(symbol);
         }                                     
         if (symbol == '-')
         {
            sb.append(symbol);                                 //Hold the values of the characters in the String
         }
         else if (symbol == 'A' || symbol == 'B' || symbol == 'C' || symbol == '2')
         {
            symbol = 2;
            sb.append(symbol);
         }
         else if (symbol == 'D' || symbol == 'E' || symbol == 'F' || symbol == '3') 
         {
            symbol = 3;
            sb.append(symbol);
         }
         else if (symbol == 'G' || symbol == 'H' || symbol == 'I' || symbol == '4') 
         {
            symbol = 4;
            sb.append(symbol);
         }
         else if (symbol == 'J' || symbol == 'K' || symbol == 'L' || symbol == '5') 
         {
            symbol = 5;
            sb.append(symbol);
         }
         else if (symbol == 'M' || symbol == 'N' || symbol == 'O' || symbol == '6') 
         {
            symbol = 6;
            sb.append(symbol);
         }
         else if (symbol == 'P' || symbol == 'Q' || symbol == 'R' || symbol == 'S' || symbol == '7') 
         {
            symbol = 7;
            sb.append(symbol);
         }
         else if (symbol == 'T' || symbol == 'U' || symbol == 'V' || symbol == '8') 
         {
            symbol = 8;
            sb.append(symbol);
         }
         else if (symbol == 'W' || symbol == 'X' || symbol == 'Y' || symbol == 'Z' || symbol == '9') 
         {
            symbol = 9;
            sb.append(symbol);
         }
         else if (symbol == '1') 
         {
            symbol = 1;
            sb.append(symbol);
         }
         else
         {
            symbol = 0;
            sb.append(symbol);
         }
      }
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb);
      return sb.toString();
   }


public static void displayResults(String userName, String formattedTelephoneNumber, String convertedTelephoneNumber)  
   { 
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for entering a phone number " + userName + ".\n The telephone number that you entered " +
         "was: " + formattedTelephoneNumber + ".\n After replacing any letters that you entered to the correct keypad numbers\n your telephone " +
         "is " + convertedTelephoneNumber + ".\n"); 

      System.exit(0);                                          //Terminate JOptionPane's running thread
   }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

In your while loops, change it from

```
while (ch != ' ')
```

to

```
while (ch != ' ' && i < telephoneNumber.length()-1)
```

Comment: Why is this so difficult for my brain to comprehend Randy?!  I feel like I am capable of writing decent code, but things still get me.  Shouldn't the ch != ' ' catch the first empty "value" and stop the loop?  Why is i < telephoneNumber.length()-1 needed in addition?  To me, at this point in my coding experience, that seems redundant (please understand that is different than me saying you are incorrect).  Thank you,  Andy

Comment: I'm not sure, you may be correct. But I feel like i is getting to a point that it's searching for a character in telephone number that is out of its index and that's why you are getting an exception.

Comment: Thanks Randy.  That does make sense.  It took care of the runtime error.  I am still getting the behavior of it asking me for my name, input for the telephone number and then just "stopping running."  I will look at it in detail, but suggestions on this will help.  You don't have to spoon feed me, but some guidance on this will help too.  Thanks again RandyFreak,  AndyFreak

Comment: @FreakyRandy,  I added you suggested code, removed System.exit(0) from the end of the correctFormat method, and placed a Message box in the main method under the call to correctFormat to display my username and the number entered.  The Message box displayed correctly (which is something that I don't understand, because I thought that you need a System.exit(0) at the end of each method that invokes the JOptionPane class).  Now; however, the problem that I am getting is this:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:622)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)
 at TelephoneNumberTranslator.convertPhoneNumber(TelephoneNumberTranslator.java:185)
 at TelephoneNumberTranslator.main(TelephoneNumberTranslator.java:29)

Comment: The reason you are running out of memory is because you continue copying the array without breaking out of it. That's just what I got from the error. Perhaps that's what the System.exit(0) was used for, although I am not sure at this point.

Comment: This seems to be an unrelated error to the original question? Did my answer solve the original problem? If it did, can you please mark it as resolved and open a new question and post your new code with the error message. Maybe even a screenshot of the message popup. I will take a look at that and help.